# Native Outer Join to Two Tables - How to rewrite to ANSI Join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a following query written in Oracle native (classic) join notation in Oracle `19.0`

```
SELECT   last_name, e.job_id, department_name, j.job_id, job_title
FROM employees e, departments d, jobs j
WHERE e.department_id(+) = d.department_id
AND e.job_id(+) = j.job_id;
```

Which returns (see sample data bellow) following result

```
LAST     JOB_ID DE     JOB_ID JO
---- ---------- -- ---------- --
Aaaa          1 D1          1 J1
Bbbb          2 D1          2 J2
                D2          1 J1
                D2          2 J2
                D2          3 J3
                D1          3 J3
```

What is the equivalent of this join in Oracle ANSI format (which I strive for as this was uncounted times recommended in comments on this site).

The best approach I can imagine is following query

```
SELECT   e.last_name, e.job_id, d.department_name, j.job_id, j.job_title 
FROM employees e RIGHT JOIN departments d
ON(e.department_id = d.department_id)
RIGHT JOIN jobs j on  e.job_id = j.job_id;
```

**But the result is quite different** which confuses me.

```
LAST     JOB_ID DE     JOB_ID JO
---- ---------- -- ---------- --
Aaaa          1 D1          1 J1
Bbbb          2 D1          2 J2
                            3 J3
```

I know that the first query in Oracle native syntax is a new feature as this query in Version `11.2` fails with

```
 ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table
```

My sample data are as follows

```
create table employees as 
select 1 id, 'Aaaa' last_name, 1 department_id, 1 job_id from dual union all
select 2 id, 'Bbbb' last_name, 1 department_id, 2 job_id from dual;

create table departments as 
select 1 department_id, 'D1' department_name from dual union all
select 2 department_id, 'D2' department_name from dual;

create table jobs as 
select 1 job_id, 'J1' job_title from dual union all
select 2 job_id, 'J2' job_title from dual union all
select 3 job_id, 'J3' job_title from dual;
```

Comment: I stopped using the old Oracle join syntax about 15(!) years ago (and you should also do so), thus I am not so familiar with it anymore. However, as far as I remember it should be `e.department_id = d.department_id(+)
AND e.job_id = j.job_id(+)` to get equivalent result.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? PS The manual & lots of other places including quetions here say how keyword outer joins work & how old Oracle outer join works for basic cases. Follow the manual or other authoritative documenation & ask about how you are stuck applying it, starting with simple cases--chopped code. If you don't say why you expect what you expect when you don't get what you expect, with justification per documentation, then you are just asking for us to rewrite yet another presentation with a bespoke tutorial with no idea what your misconceptions are

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The first two queries are different, because they are using different tables.

Comment: Again: Please explain what you expect & why when you get what you don't expect, justified by referencing authoritative documentation that you quote, because otherwise all we can to is rewrite the documentation with a bespoke tutorial with no idea what you misconceptions are. Put a [mre] in your post we can cut & paste & run from your post. Etc.

Comment: @SamuelLiew You just reopened this, but it should not be open. See my last comment (saying that my pre-edit comments still apply). No version has said why the Oracle (+) notation code would return the same as the keyword code, so it's just asking us to rewrite that documentation, to be misinterpreted again, with no idea what their misconceptions are, so we can't address them. (The edit by non-asker oramas actually wrongly removed the asker's helpful description of how they parsed the keyword code.) There's not a [mre] because this doesn't say why the outputs would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, the order does not matter. The Optimizer decides in which order the tables are joined.

Short answer to your question is: The Optimizer uses the order which will return the result as fast as possible and usually it selects the best option. The detailed answer would be much longer.

You can instruct Oracle to use to certain order by using hints. Your assumption would be correct for this query:

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ first_name, last_name, department_name, city, postal_code, street_address, country_id
FROM employees e 
   JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
   JOIN locations l USING (location_id)
   JOIN COUNTRIES USING (country_id);
```

Or you can use the `LEADING` hint:

```
SELECT /*+ LEADING(e d l c) */ first_name, last_name, department_name, city, postal_code, street_address, country_id
FROM employees e 
   JOIN COUNTRIES c USING (country_id)
   JOIN locations l USING (location_id)
   JOIN departments d ON (e.department_id = d.department_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I believe this does not change the returning result. I updated my question for a better understanding could you check it again pls?